# gPTP ingress timestamping in C

Tags: c, networking, time, ntp, ieee

I have been trying to implement ingress timestamping of gPTP event messages (SYNC and/or FOLLOW_UP) messages. Basically, there are two Time Sensitive Network (TSN) .ie. device-side and network-side, which are implemented in a 5GS. So gPTP packets flows from the NWTT-->DSTT. The algorithm, should be that all event messages are timestamped by the NWTT and sent to the DSTT. Then depending of that the link delay can be calculated.

Here is my code and I am kinda stuck after creating the socket and receiving the packets in the buffer and copying them to the PTP struct header. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Hardware timestamping need to be added to the gPTP event messages.

```c
int main() {
    int sock;
    sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_1588));
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(65537);
    memset(buffer, 0, 65537);
    struct sockaddr sockaddr;
    int sockaddr_len = sizeof(sockaddr);

    int buffer_len;
    buffer_len = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 65537, 0, &sockaddr, (socklen_t *) &sockaddr_len);
    if (buffer_len == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, (struct timespec *) &ts);

    struct ptpv2_header *ptpv2Header = (struct ptpv2_header *) buffer;

    // TODO
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a quick look at the description of tags when you add them to questions. Tag `ptp` is for Picture Transfer Protocol while you seem to deal with Precision Time Protocol.

Comment: @Gerhardh Picture Transfer Protocol?  Precision Transfer Protocol is becoming popular, a tag should be added

Comment: @Andrew Maybe, but currently the topic of [ptp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ptp) tag is clearly different. Just adding a tag that is not related with the queation at all is not the way to go.

Comment: agreed.  by the time i got here it was already gone, it was to c, ieee, and ntp.  i added time & networking. :-)

Comment: @Dancun Ogenda  Are you trying to write a Precision Transfer Protocol (PTP) implementation from scratch?  I don't know about PTP, but NTP actually has some pretty complex math in the background.  Also, for this forum, I think you are expected to have a question more specific than just ~"how do I do this?"    What have you tried?What did you get?What did you expect? --these 3, you should post yourself.  Or else you might not get many replies. :-)